# Beaglebone Black, Qt Application, and startup procedure

Tags: qt, debian, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a BBB running Debian 3.18.13-bone70. I have made a Qt application that works great. I would like this application to run on startup.

Currently, I have made a script, placed it in /etc/init.d and made a symbolic link to it in /etc/rc5.d/S05application. This all functions correctly.

The issue that I'm having is when my system boots up, I see my application briefly (<1 second) before the CLI login screen appears and hides my application.

I've tried playing around with the startup script location (moving it to rc2.d, but the same issue persists.

I have a splash screen that times out after 10 seconds, and it moves on to the next screen. After moving to the next screen the application is never hidden again. I would like to see the splash screen the entire time and hide the CLI login screen entirely. How could I go about doing this?

EDIT:

```
#!/bin/bash

export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/event1
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1

/home/root/./Scanscale -qws
```

This is the script that I use to start the application. The Qt window service is used when I start the program.

EDIT 2:

I'm running Debian 7 using the Debian 7 image from http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian from March 1, 2015. This is maintained by Robert Nelson, I'm not sure if it's a yocto build or something else.

Furthermore, it doesn't appear to be an X issue. I've stopped loading X, I no longer boot into the application and just sit on the command line waiting to log in. The system flickers at about the same point in time. Any thoughts?

I should probably also mention that I'm running it on a 4.3" LCD cape, not on the HDMI interface.

Comment: The X display manager starts up. You need to prevent that, but you need to get the window manager to start, though - normally startx would take care of that.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, I removed the /etc/rcS.d/S17x11-common script, which now prevents the X server from starting up. This has no effect on the problem I described above.

Comment: Do you need the script that starts the application? Or all boot scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You weren't specific about your system and what else is running on it.  For example, is it a yocto build and does it run the sato user interface, or is it more traditional X server with a display manager, window manager, etc?  Either way, there is a session-specific file which directs what programs get launched when the Xserver starts up.  Using matchbox, that file is .matchbox/session.  With X, it's usually xinit, which is driven by .xinitrc or .xserverrc.  Also, look at startx as another poster mentioned.  The latter can either be in your home directory or /etc/X11.  Depending on your system and configuration, likely one of those methods, customized, is what you're looking for.  See man xinit for more info.